# grep consonants in regular expression

Tags: regex, grep

I want to use grep to find words that have a specific number of consonants. But using the following command will give me consecutive consonants, How do i modify the command so that non-consecutive consonants are also OK?

```
grep -iE '[^aeiouy]{3}' filename
```

Comment: `[^aeiouy]` will actually catch ANY character that is not a vowel, which may not be what you want (numbers, symbols, etc).

Comment: @CollinD In my files there are only English letters so I think it's more easy to write this instead of the whole consonant list

Comment: it would still match spaces, punctuation marks and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
grep -iE '\b[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy]*?[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiouy]*?[aeiouy][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]\b'
```

That will match [a consonant][any number of vowels][consonant][vowel(s)][consonant]

Comment: I don't think so, basically, this will match all the words because the any character part will fill everything in

Comment: No, it won't. It HAS to match that consonant class at least three times. Please post the actual format of your file, as it may be useful. However, i've updated my answer to be a bit more complete, understanding the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -iP '^(?=(.*[^aeiouy]){3}).*$' filename
```

You can try this.This will select words which have at least `3` consonants anywhere in the string.Use `P` or `perl` mode.