# How to find words that contain at least five consecutive vowels

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file filled with English words. Now I need to find the lines with at least five consecutive vowels in it. How do I do this using grep?

Comment: Can you show us sample input and output? Not clear if file contains one or more than one word per line. If the latter, what delimits a word?

Comment: Are some vowels capitalized?

Comment: Is `y` a vowel?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit as it invalidated answers you've already received.

Comment: y isn't a vowel

Comment: And it's one word per line, every word capitalized

Comment: Now I have become curious. In which language [is "y" a vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879353/grep-consonants-in-regular-expression)?

Comment: @Cyrus Some people believe you can't have a word without any vowels and get upset when they see *"fry"*, *"sky"*, *"dry"* et al, so they declare `y` to be a *"sort of a vowel"*... ;-)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/when-is-y-a-vowel

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
grep '[aeiou]\{5\}' infile
```

This uses a bracket expression to match any vowel, and then looks for lines that have that repeated five times.

If the matching is supposed to be case insensitive:

```
grep -i '[aeiou]\{5\}' infile
```